# How do you create a boolean mask for a tensor in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I am building a custom metric to measure the accuracy of one class in my multi-class dataset during training. I am having trouble selecting the class.

The targets are one hot (e.g: the class `0` label is `[1 0 0 0 0]`):

```
from keras import backend as K

def single_class_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    idx = bool(y_true[:, 0])              # boolean mask for class 0 
    class_preds = y_pred[idx]
    class_true = y_true[idx]
    class_acc = K.mean(K.equal(K.argmax(class_true, axis=-1), K.argmax(class_preds, axis=-1)))  # multi-class accuracy  
    return class_acc
```

The trouble is, we have to use Keras functions to index tensors. How do you create a boolean mask for a tensor?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Keras and do not know if your code will work with boolean masks or explicit indices. Did you cast your mask to type boolean? tf.cast(binary_mask, tf.bool). With Theano you can use bool_mask.nonzero() to get the indices of the boolean mask. Let us know if this solution works.

Comment: Would you accept the answer which is using a callback?

Comment: Just to make sure - y_true is 2D? what does the rows and columns supposed to represent here?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Note that when talking about the *accuracy* of one class one may refer to either of the following (not equivalent) two amounts:

- The **recall**, which, for class *C*, is the ratio of examples labelled with class *C* that are predicted to have class *C*.
- The **precision**, which, for class *C*, is the ratio of examples predicted to be of class *C* that are in fact labelled with class *C*.

Instead of doing complex indexing, you can just rely on masking for you computation. Assuming we are talking about precision here (changing to recall would be trivial).

```
from keras import backend as K

INTERESTING_CLASS_ID = 0  # Choose the class of interest

def single_class_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    class_id_true = K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1)
    class_id_preds = K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
    # Replace class_id_preds with class_id_true for recall here
    accuracy_mask = K.cast(K.equal(class_id_preds, INTERESTING_CLASS_ID), 'int32')
    class_acc_tensor = K.cast(K.equal(class_id_true, class_id_preds), 'int32') * accuracy_mask
    class_acc = K.sum(class_acc_tensor) / K.maximum(K.sum(accuracy_mask), 1)
    return class_acc
```

If you want to be more flexible, you can also have the class of interest parametrised:

```
from keras import backend as K

def single_class_accuracy(interesting_class_id):
    def fn(y_true, y_pred):
        class_id_true = K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1)
        class_id_preds = K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
        # Replace class_id_preds with class_id_true for recall here
        accuracy_mask = K.cast(K.equal(class_id_preds, interesting_class_id), 'int32')
        class_acc_tensor = K.cast(K.equal(class_id_true, class_id_preds), 'int32') * accuracy_mask
        class_acc = K.sum(class_acc_tensor) / K.maximum(K.sum(accuracy_mask), 1)
        return class_acc
    return fn
```

And the use it as:

```
model.compile(..., metrics=[single_class_accuracy(INTERESTING_CLASS_ID)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding an updated version of the code from jdehesa's answer to work with the new Tensorflow API. Please upvote that as well, if you find this helpful.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

INTERESTING_CLASS_ID = 0  # Choose the class of interest

def single_class_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    class_id_true = tf.math.argmax(y_true, axis=-1)
    class_id_preds = tf.math.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)

    # Replace class_id_preds with class_id_true for recall here
    accuracy_mask = tf.cast(tf.math.equal(class_id_preds, INTERESTING_CLASS_ID), 'int32')
    class_acc_tensor = tf.cast(tf.math.equal(class_id_true, class_id_preds), 'int32') * accuracy_mask
    class_acc = tf.math.reduce_sum(class_acc_tensor) / tf.math.maximum(tf.math.reduce_sum(accuracy_mask), 1)

    return class_acc
```