# What will be the shape of y_true in Keras if list is passed as y?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm feeding keras model with generator.flow_from_directory `yield masked, [orig, masks]`. So passing a list into y input. But I don't understand what shape y_true will take in this case. `orig` and `masks` are 4d arrays of shape [32, 256, 256, 3] so I thought it should be 5d tensor but it's not the case. I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663013/what-is-y-true-and-y-pred-when-creating-a-custom-metric-in-keras) but unfortunately solutions from there don't work. `print(Y_train.shape)` gives an error and `model.summary()` doesn't print anything. `print(y_true.shape)` gives (None, None, None, None). How do I understand the shape and how do I take original list elements from y_true separately?

Comment: Can you be more specific or what you're trying to solve ?

Comment: @thushv89 I have data (image masks) used in Input calculation (masked images). Maks are generated during training. I need to pass these masks to my custom loss function. So I thought I could do it with passing y to model.fit as a list of original images and masks. But I don't understand how to split y_true and to use separately images and masks in loss calculation.