# Calculate recall for each class after each epoch in Tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to calculate the recall in both binary and multi class (one hot encoded) classification scenarios for each class after each epoch in a model that uses Tensorflow 2's Keras API. e.g. for binary classification I'd like to be able to do something like

```py
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(...)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))

model.compile(metrics=[binary_recall(label=0), binary_recall(label=1)], ...)
history = model.fit(...)

plt.plot(history.history['binary_recall_0'])
plt.plot(history.history['binary_recall_1'])
plt.show()
```

or in a multi class scenario I'd like to do something like

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(...)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3))

model.compile(metrics=[recall(label=0), recall(label=1), recall(label=2)], ...)
history = model.fit(...)

plt.plot(history.history['recall_0'])
plt.plot(history.history['recall_1'])
plt.plot(history.history['recall_2'])
plt.show()
```

I'm working on a classifier for an unbalanced dataset and want to be able to see at what point the recall for my minority class(s) starts to degrade.

I found an implementation of precision for a specific class in a multi-class classifier here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41717938/373655. I'm am trying to adapt this into what I need but `keras.backend` is still pretty foreign to me so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am also not clear on if I can use Keras `metrics` (as they are calculated at the end of each batch and then averaged) or if I need to use Keras `callbacks` (which can run at the end of each epoch). It seems to me like it shouldn't make a difference for recall (e.g. `8/10 == (3/5 + 5/5) / 2`) but this is why recall was removed in Keras 2 so maybe I'm missing something (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5794)

**Edit - partial solution (multi-class classification)**
@mujjiga's solution works for both binary classification and multi-class classification but as @P-Gn pointed out, tensorflow 2's [Recall metric](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Recall#args) supports this out of the box for multi-class classification. e.g.

```
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import Recall

model = ...

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=[
    Recall(class_id=0, name='recall_0')
    Recall(class_id=1, name='recall_1')
    Recall(class_id=2, name='recall_2')
])

history = model.fit(...)

plt.plot(history.history['recall_2'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_recall_2'])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `classification_report` of sklearn and keras `Callback` to achieve this.

#### Working code sample (with comments)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Input
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import Callback
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score, classification_report
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Model -- Binary classifier
binary_model = Sequential()
binary_model.add(Dense(16, input_shape=(2,), activation='relu'))
binary_model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
binary_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
binary_model.compile('adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

# Model -- Multiclass classifier
multiclass_model = Sequential()
multiclass_model.add(Dense(16, input_shape=(2,), activation='relu'))
multiclass_model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
multiclass_model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
multiclass_model.compile('adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')

# callback to find metrics at epoch end
class Metrics(Callback):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y if (y.ndim == 1 or y.shape[1] == 1) else np.argmax(y, axis=1)
        self.reports = []

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        y_hat = np.asarray(self.model.predict(self.x))
        y_hat = np.where(y_hat > 0.5, 1, 0) if (y_hat.ndim == 1 or y_hat.shape[1] == 1)  else np.argmax(y_hat, axis=1)
        report = classification_report(self.y,y_hat,output_dict=True)
        self.reports.append(report)
        return
   
    # Utility method
    def get(self, metrics, of_class):
        return [report[str(of_class)][metrics] for report in self.reports]
    
# Generate some train data (2 class) and train
x, y = make_classification(n_features=2, n_redundant=0, n_informative=2,
                           random_state=1, n_clusters_per_class=1)
metrics_binary = Metrics(x,y)
binary_model.fit(x, y, epochs=30, callbacks=[metrics_binary])

# Generate some train data (3 class) and train
x, y = make_classification(n_features=2, n_redundant=0, n_informative=2,
                           random_state=1, n_clusters_per_class=1, n_classes=3)
y = keras.utils.to_categorical(y,3)
metrics_multiclass = Metrics(x,y)
multiclass_model.fit(x, y, epochs=30, callbacks=[metrics_multiclass])

# Plotting 
plt.close('all')
plt.plot(metrics_binary.get('recall',0), label='Class 0 recall') 
plt.plot(metrics_binary.get('recall',1), label='Class 1 recall') 

plt.plot(metrics_binary.get('precision',0), label='Class 0 precision') 
plt.plot(metrics_binary.get('precision',1), label='Class 1 precision') 

plt.plot(metrics_binary.get('f1-score',0), label='Class 0 f1-score') 
plt.plot(metrics_binary.get('f1-score',1), label='Class 1 f1-score') 
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.show()

plt.close('all')
for m in ['recall', 'precision', 'f1-score']:
    for c in [0,1,2]:
        plt.plot(metrics_multiclass.get(m,c), label='Class {0} {1}'.format(c,m))
        
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

#### Output

[image]

[image]

#### Advantages:

- `classification_report` provides lots of metrics
- Can calculate metrics on validation data on train data by passing the same to `Metrics` constructor.

Comment: Thanks this works great! And I can even create a second instance and pass in my validation data to get validation metrics

Comment: tf.keras.utils.to_categorical eliminates need to have keras installed alongside tf

also, I think the code uses y_hat.shape[1]  before y_hat is initialized

Comment: if you fit with x,y, then the metrics should not be used with the same data. You should test with new data not with data that is used for training

Answer (score 6):

In TF2, `tf.keras.metrics.Recall` gained a `class_id` member that enables to do just that. Example using FashionMNIST:

```
import tensorflow as tf

(x_train, y_train), _ = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train[..., None].astype('float32') / 255
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train)

input_shape = x_train.shape[1:]
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),

  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),

  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation='softmax')])

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam',
  metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Recall(class_id=i) for i in range(10)])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=50)
```

In TF 1.13, `tf.keras.metric.Recall` does not have this `class_id` argument, but it can be added by subclassing (something that, somewhat suprisingly, seems impossible in the alpha release of TF2).

```
class Recall(tf.keras.metrics.Recall):

  def __init__(self, *, class_id, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.class_id= class_id

  def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
    y_true = y_true[:, self.class_id]
    y_pred = tf.cast(tf.equal(
      tf.math.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1), self.class_id), dtype=tf.float32)
    return super().update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
```

Comment: This looks promising but I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: To be compatible with tf.contrib.eager.defun, Python functions must return zero or more Tensors; in compilation of <function Function._defun_with_scope.<locals>.wrapped_fn at 0x000002512268FAE8>, found return value of type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Operation'>, which is not a Tensor.
```

Also any idea how to handle this for the binary classification scenario?

Comment: Mmh, I tested in TF 1.13.1 and assumed (wrongly) that it would also work in TF2. Something's a bit fishy in TF2 as even a simple `class Recall(tf.keras.metrics.Recall): pass` would produce the same error. Perhaps a bug in this alpha release -- at least a doc bug if those classes are not supposed to be subclassed at all.

Comment: Yeah that's very strange. I'll try to raise an issue on their github tomorrow

Comment: @rob just realized that `tf.keras.metric.Recall` has learned a new `class_id` argument in TF2, that does exactly what you need.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't notice that. That works great for multi-class classification.

Comment: I tried to implement this but encountered a shape error:  [Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68347501/16431106)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this but using a `callback` seems the best and most *kerasy* way of doing it. One side-note before I show you how:

> I am also not clear on if I can use Keras metrics (as they are
>   calculated at the end of each batch and then averaged) or if I need to
>   use Keras callbacks (which can run at the end of each epoch).

This is not true. [Keras' callbacks](https://keras.io/callbacks/) can use the following methods:

- on_epoch_begin: called at the beginning of every epoch.
- on_epoch_end: called at the end of every epoch.
- on_batch_begin: called at the beginning of every batch.
- on_batch_end: called at the end of every batch.
- on_train_begin: called at the beginning of model training.
- on_train_end: called at the end of model training.

This is true regardless of whether you are using `keras` or `tf.keras`.

Below you can find my implementation of a custom callback.

```
class RecallHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.recall = {}

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        # Compute and store recall for each class here.
        self.recall[...] = 42

history = RecallHistory()
model.fit(..., callbacks=[history])

print(history.recall)
```

Comment: Yeah I said Keras callbacks **can** run at the end of each epoch not that they have to. Thanks for the example. Now I'm just looking for the code to fill in the comment for the binary and multi class cases.