# TensorFlow/Keras Using specific class recall as metric for Sparse Categorical Cross Entropy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, tf.keras

***Update at bottom**

I am trying to use recall on 2 of 3 classes as a metric, so class B and C from classes A,B,C.

(The original nature of this is that my model is highly imbalanced in the classes [~90% is class A], such that when I use accuracy I get results of ~90% for prediciting class A everytime)

```
model.compile(
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', #or categorical_crossentropy
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Recall(class_id=1, name='recall_1'),tf.keras.metrics.Recall(class_id=2, name='recall_2')]
              )

history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size=BATCH, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y), callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint])
```

This spits out an error:

```
raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

ValueError: Shapes (None, 3) and (None, 1) are incompatible
```

Model summary is:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 120, 32)           19328
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 120, 32)           0
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNo (None, 120, 32)           128
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 120, 32)           8320
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 120, 32)           0
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 120, 32)           128
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 32)                8320
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 32)                0
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 32)                128
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 32)                1056
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 32)                0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 99
=================================================================
Total params: 37,507
Trainable params: 37,315
Non-trainable params: 192
```

Note that the model works fine without the errors if using:

```
metrics=['accuracy']
```

but [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37104) and [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42383) made me think something has not been implemented along the lines of tf.metrics.SparseCategorical***Recall***()

from

> tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()

---

So I diverted to a custom metric which decended into a rabbit hole of other issues as I am highly illeterate when it comes to classes and decorators.

I botched this together from an custom metric example (I have no idea how to use the sample_weight so I commented it out to come back to later):

```
class RelevantRecall(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):

    def __init__(self, name="Relevant_Recall", **kwargs):
        super(RelevantRecall, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.joined_recall = self.add_weight(name="B/C Recall", initializer="zeros")

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        y_pred = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
        report_dictionary = classification_report(y_true, y_pred, output_dict = True)

        # if sample_weight is not None:
        #     sample_weight = tf.cast(sample_weight, "float32")
        #     values = tf.multiply(values, sample_weight)
        # self.joined_recall.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values))

        self.joined_recall.assign_add((float(report_dictionary['1.0']['recall'])+float(report_dictionary['2.0']['recall']))/2)
 
    def result(self):
        return self.joined_recall

    def reset_states(self):
        # The state of the metric will be reset at the start of each epoch.
        self.joined_recall.assign(0.0)


model.compile(
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', #or categorical_crossentropy
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics=[RelevantRecall()]
              )


history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size=BATCH, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y), callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint])
```

This aim is to return a metric of `[recall(b)+recall(c)/2]`. I'd imagine returning both recalls seperately like `metrics=[recall(b),recall(c)]` would be better but I can't get the former to work anyway.

I got a tensor bool error: `OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a 'tf.Tensor' as a Python 'bool' is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.` which googling led me to add: `@tf.function` above my custom metric class.

This led to a old vs new class type error:

```
super(RelevantRecall, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not Function
```

which I didn't see how I had achieved since the class has an object?

As I said I'm quite new to all aspects of this so any help on how to achieve (and how best to achieve) using a metric of only a selection of prediciton classes would be really appreciated.

OR

if I am going about this entirely wrong let me know/guide me to the correct resource please

Ideally I'd like to go with the former method of using `tf.keras.metrics.Recall(class_id=1....` as it seems the neatest way if it worked.

I am able to get the recall for each class when using a similar function in the callbacks part of the model, but this seems more intensive as I have to do a model.predict on val/test data at the end of each epoch.
Also unclear if this even tells the model to focus on improving the selected class (i.e difference in implementing it in metric vs callback)

---

Callback code:

```
class MetricsCallback(Callback):
    def __init__(self, test_data, y_true):
        # Should be the label encoding of your classes
        self.y_true = y_true
        self.test_data = test_data

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        # Here we get the probabilities - longer process
        y_pred = self.model.predict(self.test_data)

        # Here we get the actual classes
        y_pred = tf.argmax(y_pred,axis=1)
        report_dictionary = classification_report(self.y_true, y_pred, output_dict = True)
        print ("\n")
  
        print (f"Accuracy: {report_dictionary['accuracy']} - Holds: {report_dictionary['0.0']['recall']} - Sells: {report_dictionary['1.0']['recall']} - Buys: {report_dictionary['2.0']['recall']}")
        self._data = (float(report_dictionary['1.0']['recall'])+float(report_dictionary['2.0']['recall']))/2
        return

metrics_callback = MetricsCallback(test_data = validation_x, y_true = validation_y)

history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size=BATCH, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y), callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint, metrics_callback)
```

---

## Update 19/07/2021

- I have resorted to using `categorical_crossentropy` for `loss` instead of `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`.
- One-hot-encoding my class/target arrays.
- Using tf recall: `[tf.keras.metrics.Recall(class_id=1, name='recall_1')`

I am now using the code below.

```
train_y = tf.one_hot(train_y, 3)
validation_y = tf.one_hot(validation_y, 3)
test_y = tf.one_hot(test_y, 3)

model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=opt,
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Recall(class_id=1, name='No'),tf.keras.metrics.Recall(class_id=2, name='Yes')]
    ) #tf.keras.metrics.Recall(class_id=0, name='Wait')

history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size=BATCH, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y), callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint])
```

Thanks to *Abhishek Prajapat*

This achieves the same overall goal and probably has a very small difference/impact on performance due to a small number of mutually exclusive classes,

**but** in the case of a very large number of mutually exclusive classes I still don't have an solution to achieving the same goal as above using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is quite simple. I have put together a example for you:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

data = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=20, n_classes=3, n_clusters_per_class=1)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(20)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), #or categorical_crossentropy
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.Recall(class_id=1)]
              )

y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(data[1], num_classes=3)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data[0], y))
dataset = dataset.batch(10)

model.fit(dataset, epochs=10)
```

Now as you can see that when you use `metrics.Recall` with a particular class id then your input y should be one-hot encoded. So if we have 3 classes then for 0 it should be -> [1, 0, 0] and so on 1 -> [0, 1, 0] and 2 -> [0, 0, 1].

Without using extra memory

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

data = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=20, n_classes=3, n_clusters_per_class=1)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(20)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), #or categorical_crossentropy
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.Recall(class_id=1)]
              )

def encode(x, y):
    y = tf.one_hot(y, 3) # Here 3 is the number of classes
    return x, y

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data[0], data[1]))
dataset = dataset.map(encode)
dataset = dataset.batch(10)

model.fit(dataset, epochs=10)
```

New example -

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

data = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=20, n_classes=3, n_clusters_per_class=1)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(20)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])

def encode(x, y):
    y = tf.one_hot(y, 3)
    return x, y

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data[0], data[1]))
dataset = dataset.map(encode)
dataset = dataset.batch(10)

m1 = tf.keras.metrics.Recall()
m2 = tf.keras.metrics.Recall()

def my_recall(y_true, y_pred):
    
    actual_a = y_true[:, 1]
    pred_a = y_pred[:, 1]
    
    actual_b = y_true[:, 2]
    pred_b = y_pred[:, 2]
    
    m1.update_state(actual_a, pred_a)
    m2.update_state(actual_b, pred_b)
    
    return (m1.result() + m2.result())/2

model.compile(
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), #or categorical_crossentropy
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics = [my_recall]
              )

model.fit(dataset, epochs=10)
```

For you updated question -

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

data = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=20, n_classes=3, n_clusters_per_class=1)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(20)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data[0], data[1]))
dataset = dataset.batch(10)

m1 = tf.keras.metrics.Recall()
m2 = tf.keras.metrics.Recall()

def my_recall(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, dtype=tf.int32)
    actual_onehot = tf.one_hot(y_true, 3)
    actual_a = actual_onehot[1]
    pred_a = tf.reshape(y_pred[1], (1,3))
    actual_b = actual_onehot[2]
    pred_b = tf.reshape(y_pred[2], (1,3))  
    m1.update_state(actual_a, pred_a)
    m2.update_state(actual_b, pred_b)   
    return (m1.result() + m2.result())/2

model.compile(
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
              optimizer='adam',          
              metrics = [my_recall]
              )

model.fit(dataset, epochs=10)
```

Comment: this is for CategoricalCrossentropy. I am using sparse_categorical_crossentropy, unless you are suggesting that sparse_categorical_crossentropy is incorrectly being used? from what I gathered [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/41921/sparse-categorical-crossentropy-vs-categorical-crossentropy-keras-accuracy), since my classes are mutually exclusive, I'd be wasting memory and time using CategoricalCrossentropy? So then is recall not available to use for sparse? which seemed to be what the github links in question posed..

Comment: I have edited the answer for not creating memory overhead but as for Recall not available for Sparse that I am not sure about but as you can see that the metrics for Sparse have `Sparce` written in their implementation so that might be the case.

Comment: @Panda if this solves your question then I will be happy to receive that bounty.

Comment: Sorry not really got the a solution here. where is this "the metrics for Sparse have Sparce written"? as for the overhead I beleive this refers to feeding the model one hot coding lables instead of integers labels, as you have more information that is not needed, not in the actual implementation of one hot. Also I said I am able to get the recall using sparse_categorical_crossentropy from a custom call back so at the very lease I expect that to be something I can do for metrics. I've added the code for that, but here it has to do another predict on valuation data which to my mind is repetition

Comment: oh... No problem. I put together another example for you. Here you go. As for "the metrics for Sparse have Sparse written" had a spelling mistake in `Sparse` and I have written that 'I am not sure' that's cause I have seen that in the metrics class name. You will be more sure if you look at this source code of Recall. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.5.0/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py#L1469-L1472.

Comment: I used your latest code with my input data. As already explained, for memory and time resources I am not using one_hot coding. Perhaps there is some issue with my inputs? I added a print statement to show my `y_true, y_pred`
`y_true = Tensor("ExpandDims:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)`
`y_pred = Tensor("sequential/dense_1/Softmax:0", shape=(None, 3), dtype=float32)`

Comment: I still get errors:

`ValueError: slice index 1 of dimension 1 out of bounds. for '{{node strided_slice_1}} = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, begin_mask=1, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=1, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=2](ExpandDims, strided_slice_1/stack, strided_slice_1/stack_1, strided_slice_1/stack_2)' with input shapes: [?,1], [2], [2], [2] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <0 1>, input[2] = <0 2>, input[3] = <1 1>.`

Comment: You have to use OHE at some point. There is no escaping it. Either you do so with the input or in the metric function.

Comment: ??? for my paticular case (if so why?) or you are saying OHE is essential regardless, I'm pretty sure the latter is wrong

Comment: look at this and then change what you want - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a4dfb8d1a71385bd6d122e4f27f86dcebb96712d/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py#L371

Comment: Hey, dude is your problem (`This aim is to return a metric of [recall(b)+recall(c)/2]. I'd imagine returning both recalls separately like metrics=[recall(b), recall(c)] would be better but I can't get the former to work anyway.`) solved? I am pretty sure it is. Also for the part of not wanting to use OHE, I don't get it what's wrong with that. It will OHE only a single batch and even then you have very few classes. There is literally no need to mention `memory and time resources` for such a trivial task.

Comment: So from the accepted answer in [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/41921/sparse-categorical-crossentropy-vs-categorical-crossentropy-keras-accuracy) I got `For case when classes are exclusive, you don't need to sum over them - for each sample only non-zero value is just −logp(s∈c) for true class c.

This allows to conserve time and memory. Consider case of 10000 classes when they are mutually exclusive - just 1 log instead of summing up 10000 for each sample, just one integer instead of 10000 floats.` But as you say I only have 3 classes. I am updating the question now

Comment: What do you mean by **I am updating the question now**. Ask a new question instead. For all I care, I looked for a solution to your problem and now you say you are changing the problem itself.

Comment: ...ok chill bro. I'm not changing the question, I am updating it as I just did. I literally said I am updating, you got to the whole **"changing the problmen itself"** on your own mate

Comment: @Panda For the last time, I have updated my answer. With that, you can use `SparseCategorialCrossEntropy`.

Comment: thanks, this appears to work but if I wanted to return and see the recall of each seperately like I have with the `CategoricalCrossentropy` how would I achieve that. I tried `return m1.result(), m2.result()` but it still only shows one value in the output

Comment: @Panda then just use `metrics = [myRecalla, myRecallb]`. Just make 2 different functions.